# jQuery - how to append values into html elements without getting them parsed as html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

Yes the question sounds weird, but what I wanna achieve is when I am appending using

`.html()` function I want **certain part** of it to behave like

`.text()` function. 
For example in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KZBAy/ ` in

```
$("#htmltest").html("<ul><li>"+**unescape(escape(testvar))**+"</li></ul>");`
```

I want the +**unescape(escape(testvar))**+ to behave as text. i.e the html tags in it should be treated as text, it should not be parsed.  This is a simple `<li>` example please provide a generic solution which can be used for all tags like appending into `<div>` tag `<table>` tag etc
**Are there any tags like `CDATA` in html which can instruct the browser not to parse  the text inside it??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the element markup, then [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the container you want to insert text into and invoke [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on it.

In your case, something like:

```
$("#htmltest").html("<ul><li></li></ul>").find("li").text(testvar);
```

Comment: Yes this will solve the current problem but I am looking for a generic solution like adding some tags similar to CDATA which will instruct the browser not to parse the text inside that tag

Comment: HTML does not know about `CDATA` sections, and markup has to be escaped even within `<pre>`. You could define your own unique marker, split the string around it and pass the relevant parts to `html()` and `text()`, but finding the appropriate text container would be difficult in the general case (and of course the marker cannot appear anywhere else in the text).

Comment: @hamidi Yea ! only cdata will work only with xml. I thought some simple way should be there instead of replacing all `< `with `\<` or something like that? 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


also in your answer if i have more than one element can i use something like this
`$("#htmltest").html("<ul><li class='foo1'></li><li class='foo2'></li></ul>").find(".foo1").text(testvar).find('.foo2').text('hhhhh');`

Answer (score 1):

Well after a lot of googling i found that it was **`<xmp>`** tag !!

Though its deprecated it has **no exact substitute** so far !!!

so where ever we want to instruct the browser not to parse we can prefix and suffix with  tag

```
   $("#htmltest").html("<ul><li><xmp>"+unescape(escape(testvar))+"</xmp></li></ul>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EgQSj/1/